# Reshape array in keras

Tags: python, keras, reshape

Is it possible in keras to `[Reshape][1]` an array in eras by only specifying one of the two dimension, such that the last dimension fits accordingly?

In my case i have (30,1,2080) and i want to reshape it to (15,)

Comment: To be exact, you probably want to have shape `(15, ?)` - but thanks for the question and answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the last dim to -1.. 
So `Reshape(15,-1)`